# google map does not show properly

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-scope

how to call initmap method in angularjs because. map does not show... properly when i use $scope.mymap = function(){}  when i clicked refresh button its working fine, but when i change the tap, and clicked map tab map show below like picture

> this.$window.initMap  how to call this method in angularjs

```
 this.$window.initMap = function () { }  //this method map was show properly, but i am using tap , this code does not work

<li><a ng-click="initMap()"  href="#map" data-toggle="tab">Map</a></li>
```

[image]

Comment: the maps  is vsible when the page is  loaded  or is in an hidden  tab?

Comment: when page load job list tab visible when i swtich my tap map ..map show like above picture

Comment: ok  .. please update your question and add the javascript code for initMap  . could be that you invoke the initMap  also  in others place  .. show me this code too

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: i am using this example

Comment: You have to call the resize event to get it work..  If you resize the map manually. Everything will show correctly hence this may solve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then  remove the callback for initMap in your call

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
async defer></script>
```

then your call should work

```
<li><a ng-click="initMap()"  href="#map" data-toggle="tab">Map</a></li>
```

and then you a check for creation

```
  <script>
    var map;
    var mapCreated = false;  
    function initMap() {
      if (mapCreated == false) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
      mapCreated = true; 
    }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer when i clicked map tab its show...again i click job list..then when i clicked again map tab its show same like above picture